# bash - trim input after string manipulation

Tags: bash, trim

This is how my input looks like:

```
string="a 1,a 2,a 3"
```

This is how I generate list out of the input:

```
sed -e 's/[^,]*/"&"/g' <<< ${string}
```

Above command gives me the desired output as:

```
"a 1","a 2","a 3"
```

How do I trim each element so that if the input is `" a 1,  a 2,      a 3"`, my output still comes back as `"a 1","a 2","a 3"`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the criteria? Give an example of some closer to real-world inputs so we see what problems we are dealing with. Otherwise I could suggest something like `sed -E 's/ *a *([0-9]) *(,?)/"a \1"\2/g'`, which does what you ask but probably isn't useful. :)

Comment: Is it always `a`? Could it be `b`? Or `abcdef`? Are the numbers always single digits? Or could it be `873`? Are there always three items separated by commas? Or could there be 4? Your question is poorly specified.

Comment: It is alphanumeric string literals separated by comma. There could be n number of items separated by comma.

Comment: @Asdfg yes, I agree, my reply was limited in scope so that the user can poke more into the possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to understand that in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), the double quotes have a special meaning.

1. `string="a 1,a 2,a 3"` represents the string `a 1,a 2,a 3` (no quotes)
2. `sed -e 's/[^,]*/"&"/g' <<< ${string}` is equivalent to the variable `out='"a 1","a 2","a 3"'`

To accomplish what you want, you can do:

```
$ string=" a 1,  a   2,      a 3 "
$ echo "\"$(echo ${string//*( ),*( )/\",\"})\""
"a 1","a 2","a 3"
```

This is only using bash builtin operations.

- replace all combinations of multiple spaces and commas by the quoted comma `${string//*( ),*( )/\",\"}`
- use word splitting to remove all leading and trailing blanks `$(echo ...)` (*note: this is a bit ugly and will fail on cases like `a  1 , a 2` as it will remove the double space between `a` and `1`)*
- print two extra double-quotes at the beginning and end of the string.

A better way is to use a double substitution:

```
$ string=" a 1,  a   2,      a 3 "
$ foobar="\"${string//,/\",\"}\""
$ echo "${foobar//*( )\"*( )/\"}"
"a 1","a   2","a 3"
```

**note:** here we make use of KSH-globs which can be enabled with the *extglob* setting (`shopt -s extglob`)

Comment: not sure why your output is different than mine. It shows `" a 1","  a   2","      a 3 "`

Comment: @ASdfg is **extglob** enabled? You can check this with `shopt extglob` and enable it with `shopt -s extglob`.

Comment: Still with `extglob` not the expected output: https://ideone.com/b9lD6x (sorry @Asdfg I wasn't able to use your CodingGround link on mobile at all).

Comment: @tripleee why is that not expected? This outputs exactly what I expected.

Comment: Oh sry, I expected spaces between `a 2` to be normalized too; but I see now that this wasn't expected or required (quite the opposite in fact). Thanks for the quick follow-up!

Comment: I believe the double spacing between a and two should be kept. If not we can use word splitting to get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Since OP told to wrap output in `"` so adding it now.

```
echo "$string" |  sed -E 's/^ +/"/;s/$/"/;s/, +/"\,"/g'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
echo "$string" |  sed -E 's/^ +/"/;s/$/"/;s/, +/"\,"/g'
"a 1","a 2","a 3"
```

---

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{sub(/^\" +/,"\"");gsub(/, +/,"\",\"")} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you want to save output into same Input_file itself append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file`.

***Solution 2nd:*** Using `sed`.

```
sed -E 's/^" +/"/;s/, +/"\,"/g' Input_file
```

Comment: with input `"a1,a2,a3"`, output is `a1,a2,a3`. With input `" a1 , a2 , a3 "`, output is `a1 ","a2 ","a3`. I need output to be `"a 1","a 2","a 3"`.

Comment: @Asdfg, I given solutions as Input_file not as variable.

Comment: Does it matter? Also I need that output assigned to a variable.

Comment: @Asdfg, so when you do `echo variable` `"a1 , a2 , a3 "` should come? I mean `"` should also come in output too? Because `echo "$var"` means to print variable along with new lines(if a variable has it or keep the characters special meaning as it is)

Comment: Yes. I need quotes wrapped around each value.

Comment: @Asdfg, please check my EDIT solution and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Your edited solution is missing beginning quote. This is what is shows `a1     ","a2     ","a3     "`. this is what i need `"a1     ","a2     ","a3     "`

Comment: @Asdfg, it is working as expected only see this `echo "$string" |  sed -E 's/^ +/"/;s/$/"/;s/, +/"\,"/g'   "a 1","a 2","a 3"` let me know then?

Comment: @Asdfg, I added expected output into EDIT solution too now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176078/discussion-between-asdfg-and-ravindersingh13).

Answer (score 0):

Here an answer which extends your sed command with some basic preprocessing that removes unwanted spaces:

```
 sed -E -e 's/ *(^|,) */\1/g;s/[^,]*/"&"/g' <<< ${string}
```

The `-E` option enables extended regular expression which saves some `\`.

Comment: with input `"a1 , a2 , a3 "`, output is `"a1 ","a2 ","a3"`. this is pretty close. All it needs is remove trailing spaces from a1 and a2.

Comment: @Asdfg I adapted the answer to the new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of complex sed pattern, you can use `grep -ow` option.

```
[nooka@lori ~]$ string1="a 1,a 2,a 3"
[nooka@lori ~]$ string2=" a 1,  a 2,      a 3,        a 4"
[nooka@lori ~]$ 
nooka@lori ~]$ echo $(echo $string1 | grep -ow "[a-zA-Z] [0-9]"|sed "s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/")|sed "s/\" /\",/g"
"a 1","a 2","a 3"
[nooka@lori ~]$ echo $(echo $string2 | grep -ow "[a-zA-Z] [0-9]"|sed "s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/")|sed "s/\" /\",/g"
"a 1","a 2","a 3","a 4"
```

1) use `grep -ow` to get only those words as per the pattern defined above. You can tweak the pattern per your needs (for ex: [a-zA-Z] [0-9][0-9]* etc) for more patterns cases.
2) Then you wrap the output (a 1 or a 2 etc) with a `"` using the first sed cmd.
3) Then you just put `,` between 2 `"` and you get what you wanted. This assumes you pattern always follows a single space between `string` and `number` value.

Comment: it gives strange output when I set string="a 1 b 1 c , a 2 , a 3, a 4". this is the output it gives me `"a 1","b 1","a 2","a 3","a 4"`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Finally got it working.

```
string="     a 1 b 2 c 3     ,     something else    ,   yet another one with spaces ,     totally working     "

trimmed_string=$(awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*/,",")}1' <<< $string)

echo ${trimmed_string}
a 1 b 2 c 3,something else,yet another one with spaces,totally working

string_as_list=$(sed -e 's/[^,]*/"&"/g' <<< ${trimmed_string})

echo ${string_as_list}
"a 1 b 2 c 3","something else","yet another one with spaces","totally working"
```

> This whole thing had to be done because terraform expects list
>   variables to be passed like that. They must be surrounded by double quotes (" "),
>   delimited by comma( , ) inside square brackets([ ]).